# Start workflow with web services Sharepoint 2010

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow, sharepoint-clientobject

I am attempting to run a visual studio sequential workflow on items in a library, but have hit a wall.   since the client object model doesn't seem to support starting workflows, I am attempting to use the web service call to "../_vti_bin/workflow.asmx" web service.

Everything seems ok up to the point where it calls

```
StartWorkflow(item, templateid, workflowParameters)
```

I get an error saying `parameters can't be null`.  My workflow has no init form, so im not sure what params to pass.  can someone help me out here?

here is my code:

```
Private Sub LoadDataFromSite()

    Try

        Dim frm As New DateForm
        frm.ShowDialog()

        fromDate = frm.DateTimePicker1.Value.Date
        toDate = frm.DateTimePicker2.Value.Date

        Dim siteUrl As String = "http://host.dom.local/payroll/"

        Dim clientContext As New ClientOM.ClientContext(siteUrl)
        Dim oList As ClientOM.List = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Timesheets")
        Dim oListItem As ListItem

        Dim camlQuery As New ClientOM.CamlQuery()
        camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View/>"

        Dim collListItem As ClientOM.ListItemCollection = oList.GetItems(camlQuery)
        clientContext.Load(collListItem)
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery()

        For Each oListItem In collListItem

            Console.WriteLine("ID: {0} " & vbCrLf & "Title: {1} " & vbCrLf & "", oListItem.Id, oListItem("Title"))

            If CDate(oListItem("Timesheet_x0020_Date")).Date >= fromDate And _
                CDate(oListItem("Timesheet_x0020_Date")).Date <= toDate Then

                MsgBox("found a timesheet in the specified date range = " & oListItem("Timesheet_x0020_Date"))

                Dim sguid As String = "{2009B982-3A49-4217-99AC-7E52C0EE44EF}"
                Dim workflowTemplateGuid As New Guid(sguid)
                Dim _itemURI As String = "http://host.dom.local/payroll/" & oListItem("Title")

                Dim workflow As WSWorkflow.Workflow = New WSWorkflow.Workflow

                workflow.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials

                workflow.StartWorkflow(_itemURI, workflowTemplateGuid, Nothing)

            End If

        Next oListItem

    Catch exs As Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException
        MsgBox("Error starting export workflow on list items.  It may not be finished yet, and you may need to export the timesheets manually." & exs.Message)
    Catch exss As Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequestException
        MsgBox("Error starting export workflow on list items.  It may not be finished yet, and you may need to export the timesheets manually." & exss.Message)
    Catch ext As Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException
        MsgBox("Error starting export workflow on list items.  Soap exception. " & ext.Message)

    End Try

End Sub
```

so I can't pass NOTHING to the function call, so what do here?

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code.

1) Item URI/URL -  its should be ows_EncodedAbsUrl of Item, you can get it from Lists.asmx

2) association data - can not be null.

you can find detailed explanation at.

http://sharepointbuzzer.com/2013/10/15/start-workflow-using-client-object-model/

I hope it solves your error.